# NetTcpBinding WCF service and Windows 7 firewall on

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, windows-firewall

I have netTCPBinding service hosting using window service. We access this service in remote service network. It work fine till. But when i **TURN ON** window firewall of hosted WCF service machine then we cant access this WCF service.
We also change setting 
"Add/enable Windows Communication Foundation Net.TCP Listener Adapter (TCP-In) in Inbound Rules in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"
Till we get error. Is any other settings need to change?

Comment: You need to open a port which you are using with netTCPBinding for WCF Service in FireWall.

Comment: Thanks Ashok...But other than Open a Port there is any another way.

Comment: Hi ashok, I open port and apply inbound and outbound rule but it works, but i want profile selected is only private and domain(i.e. not public)